# Regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have text from regular expression:

```
This post contains forecast for BTC/USDC This message was written by guest user, and is available at site.com
```

I need add with regular expression dot before like this: `"BTC/USDC. This message"`.
How can i do that?

Comment: Regular Expression seems awfully over complicated for a basic string replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) by providing a regex to find `BTC/USDC` and then return the string with the updated data using callback pattern

```js
var str= "This post contains forecast for BTC/USDC This message was written by guest user, and is available at site.com"

const newStr= str.replace(/BTC\/USDC/, (match) => {
   return `${match}.`;
})

console.log(newStr);
```